# Letter size does not stay uniform with 'fontsize' command

Tags: fonts, fontsize

I am preparing a kind of poster using class 'extarticle' with A2 size paper. I used the command to *\fontsize{1.5mm}{1.5mm}* to determine the font size. I'm using the extarticle class to have more freedom of formatting. But when I compile the LaTeX code in TEXMAKER the font size gets larger in some parts of the second column.

My question. How can I fix this?

Unfortunately I can only share the Tex codes via [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oek85sz2jkekglw/Poster_LaTeX_A2%20-%20Copia.tex?dl=0) because the error only occurs in a very large version of the file with more than 40000 characters. Thus, it exceeds the limit of 30000 characters allowed by questions here.

Comment: you must be able to take a copy of that file and delete almost all of it while still showing the size change, also (but most likely unrelated) it is very odd to use the same size for both the arguments of `\fontsize`, and did you use `\selectfont` to actually select that size?

Comment: 1.5mm is a very small font how will anyone read it?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The error occurs even when I increase the font size to 2.5mm

Comment: you never select the font, but you are specifying the font and baseline to be the same size so nothing will fit. It really was not hard to make a small MWE from your dropbox example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

You used `\fontsize` without selecting a font with `\selectfont` so it only takes effect at the next font change

```
\documentclass{article}



\begin{document}
\fontsize{1.5mm}{1.5mm}

aaa bbbb ccc 
aaa bbbb ccc 
aaa bbbb ccc 
aaa bbbb ccc 
aaa bbbb ccc 



\itshape

aaa bbbb ccc 
aaa bbbb ccc 
aaa bbbb ccc 
aaa bbbb ccc 
aaa bbbb ccc 

\end{document}
```